# Visual Studio updates ALL the dependencies packages.lock.json in a different format

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 v17.3.5.

When I add add/update/remove a package reference to a project the *packages.lock.json* files are modified, and Visual Studio writes the dependency record in this way:

```json
      "my-project": {
        "type": "Project",
        "dependencies": {
          "Npgsql": "[6.0.7, )"
        }
      },
```

The problem is that all the other members of the team have the dependencies written in this way:

```json
      "my-project": {
        "type": "Project",
        "dependencies": {
          "Npgsql": "6.0.7"
        }
      },
```

(the other developers said they also use VS 2022)

The result is that there are hundreds of line of code changed in the PR.
How can I set VS to use the simple ("6.0.7") format?

### [Update about NuGet.exe]

A colleague of mine pointed out that the lock files are create by the "restore" command by NuGet.exe.
The only NuGet.exe I have in my machine was certainly installed within the Visual Studio installation, and is here:
C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\1.13.2\cli_x64\NuGet.exe

Is possible a setting in NuGet or a different version can impact that behaviour?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74052349/4051181