# Nuget: ranges vs. specific versions in packages.lock.json dependencies

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I have a dotnet project with a `packages.lock.json` committed into my repository for Nuget. The committed version has a dependency property, that looks as following:

```
dependencies: {
  ...
  "MQTTnet": "3.0.15",
  ...
}
```

When I opened the project with the Rider IDE (from Jetbrains) it seems Nuget ran automatically in the background and changed the version to use this range syntax:

```
dependencies: {
  "MQTTnet": "[3.0.15, )",
  ...
}
```

When I inspect the lock file, I can see that some versions are using ranges while others appear to use a specific version. I would like to avoid random changes in the lock file unless I explicitly decide to update my package dependencies and when I do update I would like to have more control on when ranges vs. specific versions are used.

How can I understand why these changes happen and what is causing them?

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding of these changes:

The versions comply to SemVer (just like NPM packages).
Specifying three digits (joined by a dot) is considered an exact version.

The new format however uses an version range; inclusive minimum it's called.
As an end user (not an library author), that's not what we want. But, because all three digits are there, it's an exact version.

> So, a "plain version" like `1.2.3` is treated as version range, equivalent to `[1.2.3 , )`
> (https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/issues/6610#issuecomment-651259846)

Why this is happening right now, I couldn't find yet.
I have a suspicion that NuGet forced this new format, to support version ranges.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning

Comment: I agree, as a library author I want to specify my peer dependencies via version ranges (like npm peerDependencies), but in the lock file that my CI server uses I would expect to see explicit fixed versions. Do we know if this behavior is controlled server side or if it changed with a specific version of NuGET?

Comment: I don't know why and how. We just noticed happening last week for at least one team-member.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this has recently changed, though I suspect the default has changed within Rider/nuget (possibly [so that the package is defined using SemVer v2.0.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#semantic-versioning-200:%7E:text=For%20nuget.org,alpha.1%2C%20)). However, the two versions are equivalent to each other.

Your original version (`"MQTTnet": "3.0.15"`) does not mean the version of `MQTTnet` must be exactly `3.0.15`. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges) describes it like this:

> | Notation | Applied rule | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1.0 | x ≥ 1.0 | Minimum version, inclusive |

From reading the other examples in the documentation, I believe that the updated form (`"MQTTnet": "[3.0.15, )"`) means the same thing, because `[3.0.15` means the version must be ≥ 3.0.15, and `, )` means there is no upper bound.

An exact match would be specified like this:

```
dependencies: {
  ...
  "MQTTnet": "[3.0.15]",
  ...
}
```